# Sending Facebook friend requests through iOS App

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, xcode7, facebook-ios-sdk

Is it possible to send Facebook friend requests through an iOS application other than the Facebook app? Utilizing either Facebook's iOS SDK or Graph API? Please let me know.

Comment: The FB API doesn't offer a lot of things unfortunately as luk2302 mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, unfortunately not.
The api does not provide a way to create / accept a friend request.
You have to use the actual facebook app for that.